# Android First Application tutorial

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have created a app based on the android tutorial : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

The code is exactly the same except the app name but the application is force closing.

`06-24 16:19:22.279: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
    06-24 16:19:33.028: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
    06-24 16:19:34.568: E/BatteryService(62): usbOnlinePath not found
    06-24 16:19:34.568: E/BatteryService(62): batteryVoltagePath not found
    06-24 16:19:34.568: E/BatteryService(62): batteryTemperaturePath not found
    06-24 16:19:34.588: E/SurfaceFlinger(62): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or         /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
    06-24 16:19:34.698: E/SensorService(62): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)
    06-24 16:19:39.449: E/System(62): Failure starting core service
06-24 16:19:39.449: E/System(62): java.lang.SecurityException
06-24 16:19:39.449: E/System(62):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
06-24 16:19:39.449: E/System(62):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
06-24 16:19:39.449: E/System(62):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
06-24 16:19:39.449: E/System(62):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)
06-24 16:19:39.479: E/EventHub(62): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
06-24 16:19:39.479: E/EventHub(62): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
06-24 16:19:39.808: E/SoundPool(62): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-24 16:19:39.808: E/SoundPool(62): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
06-24 16:19:39.808: E/SoundPool(62): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
06-24 16:19:39.808: E/SoundPool(62): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
06-24 16:19:39.808: E/SoundPool(62): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
06-24 16:19:39.828: E/UsbObserver(62): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 16:19:39.828: E/UsbObserver(62):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)
06-24 16:19:39.828: E/UsbObserver(62):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)
06-24 16:19:39.828: E/UsbObserver(62):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)
06-24 16:19:40.429: E/ThrottleService(62): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
06-24 16:19:40.958: E/logwrapper(137): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-24 16:19:41.069: E/logwrapper(139): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-24 16:19:41.129: E/logwrapper(144): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  ... 11 more
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.myfirstapp.MyFirstActivity.sendMessage(MyFirstActivity.java:26)
06-24 16:37:58.420: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  ... 14 more
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  ... 11 more
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.myfirstapp.MyFirstActivity.sendMessage(MyFirstActivity.java:26)
06-24 16:38:47.529: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  ... 14 more
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  ... 11 more
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.myfirstapp.MyFirstActivity.sendMessage(MyFirstActivity.java:26)
06-24 16:43:20.070: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  ... 14 more
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  ... 11 more
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at com.myfirstapp.MyFirstActivity.sendMessage(MyFirstActivity.java:26)
06-24 16:45:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  ... 14 more
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  ... 11 more
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  at com.myfirstapp.MyFirstActivity.sendMessage(MyFirstActivity.java:26)
06-24 18:20:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(464):  ... 14 more
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  ... 11 more
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.myfirstapp.MyFirstActivity.sendMessage(MyFirstActivity.java:26)
06-24 18:25:12.590: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  ... 14 more

<code>`

not sure as how to debug this app.
Please advice

Thanks

SSAMEERR

Answer (score 1):

- Unable to find explicit activity class
  {com.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java.DisplayMessageActivity};
  have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

put the entry of the DisplayMessageActivity in manifest.......

it DisplayMessageActivity is first Activity use intent-filter other remove that.

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" android:label="Demo App">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: @SSAMEERR if still found any issue update complete manifest so that we are to give more accurate answer....

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the logcat:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

[Declare the activity in your manifest](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#AddToManifest) like so (i.e. insert it somewhere between the `<application>` and `</application>` tags):

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
```

This is a common beginners mistake... expect this error at least a couple more times before you get used to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the DisplayMessageActivity manifest as

```
<application ... >
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your other activities in the project are added to the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your activity in Manifest like:

```
<activity android:name=".MyFirstActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        </activity>
```